# How to organize data in Redis for multiple resource to be used for autocomplete search

Tags: search, autocomplete, redis

I have following resources (example):

- account
- company
- person

Each of these resources should be searchable by one `field`: `account.name`, `company.name`, `person.name`. Now I want to take 'aggregated' list of data from all of these resources by some phrase in autocomplete, for example `ta...` etc. So this list should be sorted by its `name`.

**How to implement such `indexing` for autocomplete in Redis?** I started with Soulmate approach I took from [**here**](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/29/two-ways-of-using-redis-to-build-a-nosql-autocomplete-search-index) (it's the second approach shown there)

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned link is the implementation of the second approach.
I am currently using it. Its contained in an app.

Files description:
filler.py - Fills the data from a datasource into the redis.
views.py  - The point where the keywords to be autocompleted are hit.

https://github.com/dan-boa/lidea/tree/master/suggest